# What is the syntax for using 410 status for deleted pages?

Tags: http

I want to permanently delete some pages in my site using 410 status. I'm not sure of correct syntax of removing pages using 410.

I've found one syntax and I've a page( duplicate product page content) to remove : http://www.creditcardpaymentgateways.in/indiapay-payment-gateway-frequently-asked-questionsfaq.html

so will this syntax do?

```
RewriteRule ^indiapay-payment-gateway-frequently-asked-questionsfaq.html$ - [G,L]
```

In my site I have a couple of duplicate product pages which I want to remove as my site is getting penalized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rewrite rule is fine for the page that's been deleted. It will return a 410 error for that page only.

If there's a good reason to keep any of the duplicate pages, you can use a [canonical link tag](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html) in the head of the duplicate page, containing the preferred URL you want Google to use when indexing those pages. e.g.:

`<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.yoursite.in/payment.html" />`

Comment: If I keep them using this technique suggested by you( rel=canonical) are your sure there won't be any duplicate content penalty for it?

Comment: @John No. Indicating the preferred URL for essentially-identical pages is [the entire purpose](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=139394) of rel-canonical.

Comment: @John Google explains clearly how duplicate content works [here.](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2008/09/demystifying-duplicate-content-penalty.html) If you're duplicating content innocently, and doing your best to tidy it/point crawlers to the canonical page, you shouldn't be penalised for it.

Comment: Nick I want your suggestion for the comment below from Kevin.

Comment: @John Kevin's advice is great (+1 from me). Use canonical links when the two similar pages are unique enough to be worth keeping. 301 redirect dupes that are very similar. 410 pages that don't have a duplicate to redirect to.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a duplicate page which you have no reason to keep, you should not 410 it, nor leave it up, but instead use a 301 (Moved Permanently) redirect to the other copy. In this way, any links or bookmarks to the removed page will not be broken.